# Isomorphism from $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4)$ to $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4) \simeq D_8$ (isometry group of square)

I' have got an idea to show isomorphisms : $f: Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $g:\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow D_8$

So, $f \circ g : Aut(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4) \rightarrow D_8$

$D_8 = \{ s,g \in D_8 : g^4 = e, s^2 = e, sgs=g^{-1}\}$

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x& (0,0)& (0,1) & (0,2) & (0,3) & (1,0) & (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) \\ \hline
g(x) &e &g & g^2 & g^3 & s& gs & g^2s & g^3s\\ \hline
\end{array}$

But what $f$ function could be an isomorphism?

Comment: Recall the definition of isomorphism, then, if you want to solve the problem quite brute-forcely but still effectively, simply try explicitly all possibilities for the image of the generators (1,0) and (0,1) (since once you have set those the rest just follows)... keep only the ones which "behave well" with the definition and you will see that those will generate the group you are looking for :)

Comment: The (implied) statement in the title of this post is wrong!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: He means that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_8$... hence your whole idea of finding such an f and g actually cannot work... Actually $D_8 \cong \mathbb{Z}_n \ltimes \mathbb{Z}_2$, a semidirect product

Comment: But $g(x)$ is bijection

Comment: but if it were a morphism you should have:
$g(x\circ_1y)=g(x)\circ_2g(y)$ which in this case doesn't work. For example you would have: $sg=g(1,0)g(0,1)=g((1,1))=gs$ which indeed is a contradiction because you would have shown that $sgs=g$

Comment: Ok. You are right, I am wrong, sorry.

Comment: Try to go back to my first comment and see if that works out for you... The first constraint I would work with is probably the one that implies that the order of the element in the image must be the same as the original one... this should cross out most of the possibilities

Comment: But in $Z_2 x Z_4$ I have got : 3 elements of order 2, 4 elements of order 4 and id. In $D_8$ I have  got 5 elements of order 2, 2 elements of order 4 and id